# How to stream a response from an API route back to a page in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js

In my Next.js 13 application. I created an API route to a external endpoint which will stream back the response like this,

```
export const POST = async (request) => {
  const { title } = await request.json();

  // calling external API
  const res = await fetch(
    "http:...",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(title),
    },
  );

  const reader = res.body.getReader();

  const out = new TransformStream();
  const writer = out.writable.getWriter();

  while (true) {
    const { done, value } = await reader.read();
    if (done) {
      break;
    }
    // this seems to be okay, I can see the data returned in chunks ...
    console.log(">>> " + value);
  }

  // but, how can I stream the same chunks back to my page?
};
```

From the console log, it looks like I'm able to get the streaming response chunk by chunk. But how can I stream the same chunks back to my page?

Comment: You need to fetch your API route from the frontend. You should probably add a rough idea of your file structure it might help us answer your question.